# Query to count of different groups in to single row

Tags: sql

I wrote a sql using a group by class and result looks as below

```
Car_type_cd   COUNT(1)

   30           123
   40           49798 
   50           10
   60           20
   70           30
```

Now my requirement is have like if the card_type_cd is 30 or 40 i need the individual counts and else i need the count of counts i.e(30+10+20=60). Result should like below:

```
Card_type_cd   count(1)
   30            123
   40            49798
   50            60
```

Can someone provide some approach for this?

Here is the statement:

```
  SELECT ct.card_type_desc,
         count(1) 
    FROM nss.customer_alias ca, 
         nss.card_type ct, 
         nss.acct_no_store ans, 
         nss.nss_order n, 
         nss.order_line l, 
         nss.fulfillment_Schedule fs 
   WHERE ca.card_type_cd in (30,40,1260,1280,1340,3040) 
     AND ca.acct_seq = ans.acct_seq 
     AND ca.cust_id = ans.cust_id 
     AND ca.cust_id = n.cust_id 
     AND ca.card_type_cd = ct.card_type_cd 
     AND n.ordeR_id = l.order_id 
     AND l.cancel_date IS NULL 
     AND l.order_id = fs.order_id 
     AND l.line_item = fs.line_item 
     AND fs.renewal_date > SYSDATE 
GROUP BY ct.card_type_desc;
```

Comment: You wrote an sql and do not want to show it to anyone?

Comment: What is the SQL that you wrote?

Comment: seems like you need to add a where clause?

Comment: select ct.card_type_desc,count(1) 
        from nss.customer_alias ca, nss.card_type ct, nss.acct_no_store ans, nss.nss_order n, nss.order_line l, nss.fulfillment_Schedule fs
where   ca.card_type_cd in (30,40,1260,1280,1340,3040) 
        and ca.acct_seq = ans.acct_seq
        and ca.cust_id = ans.cust_id
        and ca.cust_id = n.cust_id
        and ca.card_type_cd = ct.card_type_cd
        and n.ordeR_id = l.order_id
        and l.cancel_date IS NULL
        and l.order_id = fs.order_id
        and l.line_item = fs.line_item
        and fs.renewal_date > SYSDATE
group by ct.card_type_desc;

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a `case` statement to define the groups.  This is a powerful approach to combining groups.  In this case, you can do it directly on `card_type_cd`:

```
select (case when card_type_cd < 50 then card_type_cd else 50 end) as card_type_cd,
       count(*) -- or whatver
from YourTableHere t
group by (case when card_type_cd < 50 then card_type_cd else 50 end) 
order by 1;
```

For your query, you can replace the `card_type_cd` in the `select` and `group by` with the expression `(case when card_type_cd < 50 then card_type_cd else 50 end)`.

You really do need to start using modern `join` syntax, where the join conditions go in the `on` clause.

Comment: If i want to use varchar columns in group like card_type_desc instead of card_type_cd, can you tell me the approach

Comment: @user3311626 . . . The syntax is the same.  Just change the `else` clause to have a string constant:  `else '50'`.